# AWS Redshift - Case Insensitive sorting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How can I have case insensitive sort in Redshift? 
In our application, we build and then run queries to sort based on different fields of contact table (first name, last name, date of birth, phone number etc) and for string fields, lower case last names, for example, come before upper case last names. for example sorting by last name will show brown, mcdonald, Alton, Smith, ... We want to see the list as Alton, brown, mcdonlad, Smith, ...
I am aware of workarounds (order by UPPER() function, having separate fields for display and sort, ...) but given the number of sort-able fields in contact table and mix of data types (string, date, integer) I can't use these workarounds.
I appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is no straightforward way to do this.

Apart from the workarounds you've already mentioned, I can suggest one more: you can [create a view](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html), which will have data in all lower case, and use the view for sorting data.

Comment: Thanks Ketan. Can you please elaborate on how creating a view can be a workaround?